# How to use foreach on JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda

In My code I want to use foreach action on the JavaPairRDD using lambda expression Here is the code

```
    JavaPairRDD<Integer,Tuple2<String,Integer>> 
    studentScore=students.join(scores);
    studentScore.foreach((x,y)->{
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);

    });
```

but there is a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You try to pass to *foreach* method lambda with two parameters whereas it acepts lambda with one parameter. Replace line

```
studentScore.foreach((x,y)->{
```

with line

```
studentScore.foreach(t->{
```

And use whole tuple *t* instead of *x* and *y*. Or you can extract *x* and *y* from *t* yourself.